# "Unbound local error" with accessing a variable from one function in another

Tags: python, oop, python-2.7, gis, arcgis

So I think I'm getting a hold on the OOP stuff, but right when I think I'm understanding it, something unexpected happens.

I'm assigning a variable that's been created in one function into another, and then altering it (note, this is **not** a global, I've learned my lesson about that).  But I'm still getting an unbound local error, which is confusing me.  I've read through most of the documentation here and elsewhere about this error, and I haven't found an answer to this specific question.

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Users\Tony DiBiase\AppData\Local\ESRI\Desktop10.2\AssemblyCache\{2801A62B-53E6-17B4-D465-BB6072FDEEF9}\parameterizer_final_addin.py", line 115, in onClick
num = domainNumber.text
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'domainNumber' referenced before assignment
```

And here's what I'm attempting to do (editing out the exogenous parts for brevity):

```
class domainNumber(object):
"""Implementation for parameterizer_final_addin.domainNumber (ComboBox)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = ["3000", "1000", "200", "100"]
        self.editable = True
        self.enabled = True
        self.dropdownWidth = 'WWWWWW'
        self.width = 'WWWWWW'
        self.hinttext = "Cell resolution (m^2)"
    def onEditChange(self, text):
        #so pass the text changed to a domainNumber.text, which can be passed to other    functions
        self.text = text

class printFinal():
    """Implementation for parameterizer_final_addin.printFinal"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        #iterate through domains, using number set in domainNumber
        counter = 0
        num = domainNumber.text #So calling the variable from the other function
        num = num-1
        #run the business logic for the esri pythonaddin
        while counter < num:
            ~do stuff
            num+=1 #to iterate through and finish the loop
```

So what's pretty apparent is that the error occurs when I try to **alter** the `domainNumber.text` variable inside the `printFinal` class.  But that's what's confusing me, because the `printFinal` class isn't trying to alter a global variable, and when I call the `domainNumber.text` **inside** the `printFinal` class, it should be local (and thus editable) in the `printFinal` namespace?  I mean, I specifically am saving `domainNumber.text` **into** a local variable, and then altering **that** rather than trying to alter `domainNumber.text` itself.

Right?  I access variables from other functions elsewhere in my code, and don't encounter this problem, it's only because I'm subtracting it by 1 here that's encountering the problem.   How can I get it to do that, without just making the variable global (which I'm trying to avoid)?

Comment: The error is not there. Where are you using `domainNumber`?

Comment: sorry, accidentally copied the wrong class (that does something similar.  In this instance, setRes and domainNumber are exactly the same.  I'll change the question to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

domainNumber is a *class*. 
text is an attribute on an instance of domainNumber.

To get it to work you should create an object of type domainNumber:

```
dn = domainNumber()
dn.onEditChange("123")
```

...

```
num = dn.text
```